# Quick way to read 3 columns of a 1 million column CSV file

Tags: java, csv, memory-management, io, bufferedreader

Suppose I have a CSV file with 1 million columns, hundreds of gigabytes.

My objective is to read every row of the 1st, 20th and 50th columns of this CSV file to memory as quickly as possible.

How do I achieve this? Something like this will work but is inefficient in terms of speed and memory since I need to parse every single column which is 1 million elements -- looking for a better solution that doesn't require this.

```
BufferedReader stream = ...;//reader
while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] keep = line.split(",");
   //keep only 0th,19th,49th elements.
}
```

Comment: An interview question?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No. A data mining problem I'm facing where I only want to read a small subset of columns.

Comment: 1. You could avoid the creation of 50+ array items, by using string functions to find the position of the 0th, 19th, and 49th elements from line.  2. You could read stream one character at a time and turn on and off parsing by counting newlines and commas but I suspect that this custom code could become slower than letting the full readLline String get created.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the linux command cut to retrieve those columns into a separate file and then process that file instead.

```
cut -c1,20,50 giant.csv >> just3columns.csv
```